# spawn with args in ruby

Tags: ruby, spawn

how to start a spawn in ruby, passing it the arguments?
I tried to like this:

```
validators_pid << spawn(RbConfig.ruby, "#{Dir.pwd}/../lib/validator.rb", 3, 5)
```

in validator.rb

```
puts ARGV.length
```

always outputs 0

Comment: What are the values 3 and 5 supposed to be, because currently your code gives me an error -> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Integer into String

Comment: @grail arguments must be numbers

Comment: even if they are strings, I can them .to_i in validator

Comment: You missed the part where I said it causes an error. The numbers must be passed as strings, then I get no errors and the correct output

Comment: @grail You run spawn in the same way? `phone_validators_pid << spawn(RbConfig.ruby, "#{Dir.pwd}/../lib/validator.rb", "3", "5")` I have the same outputs 0

Comment: I used = instead of << as I do not know what your variable is supposed to be but that didn't work either (more errors), then I get 2

Answer (score 1):

are you running on some weird operating system or with a crazy ruby version?

if you look into the ruby docs, those are the examples:

```
pid = spawn("tar xf ruby-2.0.0-p195.tar.bz2")
Process.wait pid

pid = spawn(RbConfig.ruby, "-eputs'Hello, world!'")
Process.wait pid
```

the last example can be changed to do what your example code does.

i ran it in a irb session:

```
irb(main):011:0> pid = spawn(RbConfig.ruby, "-eputs ARGV.length", '1', '2', '3')
=> 84399
irb(main):012:0> 3
```

Comment: The reason was negligence. In the root process, I had not noticed that require this "validator" file, and when connect it executed without any arguments. That is, the error does not appear in the spot where I thought